# A simpler method or more descriptive answer to the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals

I'm trying to do a CT Fourier Transform of these two signals
$$x_1(t)=e^{−a(t−1)} \cdot u(t−1)$$
and
$$x_2(t)=e^{−a(t−1)} \cdot u(t)$$
Where $a$ is any real number, and $u(t)$ is the unit step function and that is multiplication, not convolution.

[Picture of my work and answers here.](http://chattypics.com/files/droidUpload_qdg2kdu2di_yp4yyclp6d.jpg)

The answers listed should not contain the extra 
$$t \cdot u(t-1)$$ and $$t \cdot u(t)$$

Okay, thanks to Dilip i now have my answers to look like 
$$ x_1(F)=\frac{e^{2a+j2\pi\cdot F}}{a+j2\pi\cdot F}$$
and 
$$x_2(F) =\frac{e^a}{a+j2\pi\cdot F} $$
That does seem more elegant than what i previously had, I feel like I could possibly manipulate $x_1(F)$ into a sinc function, but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Please check your displayed formulas.  Right now, they don't make sense.  Also, does that $*$ stand for a convolution or multiplication? Once you have corrected the question, _draw_ a diagram of the signals whose Fourier transforms you seek. Then it should be fairly straightforward via a _change of variables_ such as putting $-j\omega-a(t-1) = u$.  $U(t)$ or $U(t-1)$ merely changes the **limits** on the integral; they **DO NOT** appear inside the integral at all as you have done in your work that you have linked to.

Comment: I understand what the signals would look like, but how does that help? And i don't really get why changing the variables would help give a nicer answer. I do see that i made that mistake when integrating the u(t).

Comment: U(t-n) essentially sets the limits of integration.  The integration starts at n and ends at infinity.  Once you get the limits right, the U(t-n) portion of the time domain function is redundant and can be tossed.  After that, a change of variables as suggested by Dilip may simplify the integration.  Note that once you perform the integration and apply the limits, t will be gone from the result (generally no functions of t remain in a Fourier transform).

Comment: I find easier just integrating from 1 to infinite the exponential(by removing the unit step from integrand),this way you get a simple integral to solve.

Comment: @DanielConde - Exactly :-)

Comment: **I understand what the signals would look like, but how does that help?**  Well, if we know that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x < a$ (e.g. if $f(x)=g(x)u(x-a)$), then $$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx&= \int_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx+\int_a^\infty f(x)dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^a 0 dx+\int_a^\infty g(x)dx\\&= \int_a^\infty g(x)dx.\end{align}$$

Comment: So is there still a question remaining here? It looks like this question can be closed.

Comment: Nope, no question left. I would've selected an answer but nobody posted anything in the answer section.

Comment: @retroredeye, posting the same question on multiple SE sites at once is considered rude.